# Does the hyperledger fabric 1.4 node sdk depend on the Node standard library APIs?

Tags: node.js, react-native, hyperledger-fabric, expo

The reason why I ask is that I want to use React-Native to access my blockchain.  I'm using Expo, and from the Expo Documentation:

"The Node standard library is a set of functionality implemented largely in C++ that exposes functions to JavaScript that aren't part of the JavaScript language specification, such as the ability to read and write to your filesystem. React Native, and by extension Expo, do not include the Node standard library,"

If the hyperledger fabric 1.4 node sdk does rely on the standard library, does anyone know of a work around?